# How to retrieve the first values in each group of a group_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

How would you find all the first/top values in a query that uses a group by? So I want to find the first record in each grouped month:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :foo
  attr_accessible :month, :votes, :foo_id
  # ...
end
```

So in the model above I want to retrieve the records that have the most votes for each month. The records are already ordered by votes descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will filter all the data according to month wise and you can go to in it with each loop and get first record from that.

```
month_wise = Log.all.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }

month_wise.each do |month|
puts month.first.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map):
`tops = Log.all.group_by{ |l| l.created_at.month }.map(&:first)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, you can use [transform_values](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values)

```
Log.all.group_by{ |l| l.created_at.month }.transform_values(&:first)
```